# how to get particular part of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame "df" as below:

```
           lat      lon         time
ID                                  
48202  42.5040 -70.5419  731800.5514
48202  42.4956 -70.5539  731801.6319
48202  42.4927 -70.5830  731802.7188
48202  42.5028 -70.6010  731802.8014
48202  42.5168 -70.5966  731803.8944
48202  42.5202 -70.5746  731804.9729
48202  42.5115 -70.5528  731804.0521
48202  42.5020 -70.5427  731805.1410
...     ...     ...       ...
```

and two particular values:

```
t0=731801
t1=731803
```

Now I want to extract the part of DataFrame "df" whose "time" values between t0 and t1, as below:

```
      lat      lon         time
ID   
48202  42.4956 -70.5539  731801.6319
48202  42.4927 -70.5830  731802.7188
48202  42.5028 -70.6010  731802.8014
48202  42.5168 -70.5966  731803.8944
```

How can I do that ? I use "df.ix"method

```
df=df.ix[df['time']<=t1 and df['time']>=t0]
```

but it didn't work. The error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should mask here!

```
df_masked = df[(df.time <= t1) & (df.time >= t0)]
```